# Finding the address of a control register for a serial port in Ubuntu (or UBOOT)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, serial-port, rs232

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and serial ports.

I'm trying to find the address of the control register, that controls serial port 1 in Ubuntu. The Serial Port is using the RS232 method to communicate 
I need to do this so i can read the value that is stored in the address register.

Why? 
I want to do this so i can test my board to see if the internal loopback is working. I understand that there are two ways to test the internal loopback 
1) You can Configure the UART to act as an internal Loopback 
2) You can get the Transceiver to act as a loopback

I'm currently trying to figure out a way I can find out which register decides if the internal loopback needs to occur

Comment: *"I'm trying to find the address of the control register, that controls serial port 1 in Ubuntu"* Why? This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157730) type question. If you instead ask about what you are actually trying to accomplish, we may be able to provide relevant suggestions. Also note that programming-specific questions are off topic on [su] and should be posted on [so] instead.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I didn't think this was a programming question. The solution i provided was just a simply string you had to type in the Linux terminal.
I have also edited my original question so now people can understand why i'm asking this question

Answer (score 0):

If you type "*dmesg | grep tty*" into your command terminal if will give you an address for the register in which data is stored for that specific port (I don't believe it is the control register). It also tells you which serial ports are connected. (I wouldn't use this command to check which serial ports are connect to the computer because it tells you all the available serial ports, from first hand experience this command was telling me that a serial port was available for use when it was not (it was connected to the BMM) )

You can read the values of the register, if you are running Uboot. Simply type "*mm __*" __= address of register